# How to build a normalized tf dataframe?

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp, information-retrieval

I want to apply this into my tf function. [image] But unable to build the function.

---

My dataset looks like this
[image]

I have tried to buield the function like this

```
def term_document_matrix(data, vocab_list = None, doc_index= 'ID', text= 'text'):
      tf_matirx = pd.DataFrame(columns=df[document_index], index= vocab).fillna(0)
    a = int(input("enter the value"))
    for word in tf_matrix.index:
    
    for doc in data[document_index]:
        
        result = a + (1-a)*[data[data[document_index] == doc][text].values[0].count(word)/X]
        X = ????????
        tf_matrix.loc[word,doc] = result
return tf_matrix
```

But unable to build this completely.

Here parameters are described as below

> ```
> parameter:
> ```

```
    data: DataFrame. 
    Frequency of word calculated against the data.
    
    vocab_list: list of strings.
    Vocabulary of the documents    
    
    doc_index: str.
    Column name for document index in DataFrame passed.
    
    text: str
    Column name containing text for all documents in DataFrame,
    
returns:
    tf_matrix: DataFrame.
    DataFrame containing term document matrix.
    """
```

**My goal is to get a dataframe like this**
[image]

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example instead of pictures.

Comment: I have also given code,which I have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine tf dataframe by using CountVectorizer. Then divide each value by max value of it's column and repeat this process for every column in your dataframe

```
 df_1st = df.apply(lambda col: col / col.max())
```

and then just multiply and add a scaler for each element in your dataframe.

```
df_2nd = df_1st.apply(lambda col: lambda + col*(1-lambda))
tf_matrix = df_2nd
```